# Weird behavior merging 2 class functions and passing variables by reference

Tags: c++, class, function, pass-by-reference

I have the following two class functions which I'm attempting to merge into one because they are very similar:

```
void Camera::UpdateCameraPosition(void) {
    if(cameraMode == CAMERA_MODE_THIRD_PERSON) {
        float alpha = Math::DegreesToRadians(Rotation.y);
        float beta = Math::DegreesToRadians(Rotation.x);

        Position.SetValue(
            Player.x + CAMERA_ORBIT_OFFSET * cos(beta) * sin(alpha),
            Player.y + CAMERA_ORBIT_OFFSET * sin(-beta),
            Player.z + CAMERA_ORBIT_OFFSET * cos(beta) * cos(alpha)
        );
    } else {
        Position = Player;
    }
}

void Camera::UpdatePlayerPosition(void) {
    if(cameraMode == CAMERA_MODE_THIRD_PERSON) {
        float alpha = Math::DegreesToRadians(Rotation.y);
        float beta = Math::DegreesToRadians(Rotation.x);

        Player.SetValue(
            Position.x - CAMERA_ORBIT_OFFSET * cos(beta) * sin(alpha),
            Position.y - CAMERA_ORBIT_OFFSET * sin(-beta),
            Position.z - CAMERA_ORBIT_OFFSET * cos(beta) * cos(alpha)
        );
    } else {
        Player = Position;
    }
}
```

As you can see, `Player` and `Position` are two private variables of the class. They're data type is `Vector3D`, another class.

I'm trying to merge them like this:

```
void Camera::UpdateCameraOrPlayerPosition(Vector3D &target, Vector3D reference) {
    if(cameraMode == CAMERA_MODE_THIRD_PERSON) {
        float alpha = Math::DegreesToRadians(Rotation.y);
        float beta = Math::DegreesToRadians(Rotation.x);

        target.SetValue(
            reference.x - CAMERA_ORBIT_OFFSET * cos(beta) * sin(alpha),
            reference.y - CAMERA_ORBIT_OFFSET * sin(-beta),
            reference.z - CAMERA_ORBIT_OFFSET * cos(beta) * cos(alpha)
        );
    } else {
        target = reference;
    }
}
```

This compiles and such but it doesn't behave the same. While the other two functions are working, when I replace those function calls to this one instead, it doesn't work as it should.

The replacements I did are these:

```
UpdatePlayerPosition() -> UpdateCameraOrPlayerPosition(Player, Position)
UpdateCameraPosition() -> UpdateCameraOrPlayerPosition(Position, Player)
```

I also tried with a pointer instead of reference, the result was the same. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You have changed the use of `CAMERA_ORBIT_OFFSET` from + to - in the case of `UpdateCameraPosition() -> UpdateCameraOrPlayerPosition(Position, Player)`

Comment: I'm such an idiot... and blind :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll notice that target.SetValue uses + for Camera and - for Player when adjusting the X Y and Z coordinates.